# TableView Disappears on segmented control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a uitableviewcontroller with a segmented control in the navigation bar. I can get the tableview to reload the first time at index 0 and the second time at index 1. When I try to go back to the first index and the entire tableview disappears.

The problem only occurs when the segmented control index is 1 and the tableview section 2 is empty. If there are objects in that area, It works fine and I can switch back and forth between the two tableviews.

I also realized that when I pulled down the refresh control, it says that I have an empty array in the debug area. I put breakpoints within the refresh control method to see what the problem with that was and the problem is before the refresh control method gets fired off...how??

This is not a duplicate question and would appreciate any help I can seeing as this the place to go for all answers. Thanks!

Also, the entire uitableviewcontroller class is extremely long so if you would really like to see it please ask

NewsFeed.m File https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10826637/NewsTableViewController.m

VERY LONG

```
#import "NewsTableViewController.h"
#import "OtherNewsViewController.h"
#import "MSCellAccessory.h"

@interface NewsTableViewController ()
{
    PFUser *_loggedInUser;
    NSIndexPath *_newIndexPath;
    PFObject *_clubInvite;
    PFObject *_clubRequest;
    UIRefreshControl *_refreshControl;
    PFUser *_clubInviteUser;
    PFUser *_clubRequestUser;
    int _rowOneCount;
    int _rowTwoCount;
    NSMutableArray *_myFollowingArray;
}
@end

@implementation NewsTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
    [self.segmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changedValue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    _refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [_refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview:_refreshControl];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    _loggedInUser = [PFUser currentUser];

    _myFollowingArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_loggedInUser[@"Following"]];
    if (![_myFollowingArray containsObject:_loggedInUser.username]) {
        [_myFollowingArray addObject:_loggedInUser.username];
    }



    if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

            PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
            [userQuery whereKey:@"username" containedIn:_myFollowingArray];

            PFQuery *newsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"News"];
            [newsQuery whereKey:@"Notified" matchesQuery:userQuery];
            [newsQuery setLimit:50];
            [newsQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
            [newsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                self.followingNews = objects;
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }];

    } else if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        PFQuery *inviteQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClubInvites"];
        [inviteQuery whereKey:@"Invited" equalTo:_loggedInUser];
        [inviteQuery whereKey:@"Accepted" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        [inviteQuery countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {

            _rowOneCount = number;
            [self.tableView reloadData];

        }];

        PFQuery *requestsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClubRequests"];
        [requestsQuery whereKey:@"Owner" equalTo:_loggedInUser];
        [requestsQuery whereKey:@"Accepted" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        [requestsQuery countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {

            _rowTwoCount = number;
            [self.tableView reloadData];

        }];

        PFQuery *myNewsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"News"];
        [myNewsQuery setLimit:50];
        [myNewsQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
        [myNewsQuery whereKey:@"Notified" equalTo:_loggedInUser];
        [myNewsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            self.myNews = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];

        }];

    } else if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }





}

- (void)changedValue {
    if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
        [userQuery whereKey:@"username" containedIn:_myFollowingArray];

        PFQuery *newsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"News"];
        [newsQuery setLimit:50];
        [newsQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
        [newsQuery whereKey:@"Notified" matchesQuery:userQuery];
        [newsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            self.followingNews = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];
    } else if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        PFQuery *inviteQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClubInvites"];
        [inviteQuery whereKey:@"Invited" equalTo:_loggedInUser];
        [inviteQuery whereKey:@"Accepted" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        [inviteQuery countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
            _rowOneCount = number;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];

        PFQuery *requestsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClubRequests"];
        [requestsQuery whereKey:@"Owner" equalTo:_loggedInUser];
        [requestsQuery whereKey:@"Accepted" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        [requestsQuery countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
            _rowTwoCount = number;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];

        PFQuery *myNewsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"News"];
        [myNewsQuery setLimit:50];
        [myNewsQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
        [myNewsQuery whereKey:@"Notified" equalTo:_loggedInUser];
        [myNewsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            self.myNews = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];

    } else if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

-(void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {
    if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
        [userQuery whereKey:@"username" containedIn:_loggedInUser[@"Following"]];

        PFQuery *newsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"News"];
        [newsQuery whereKey:@"Notified" matchesQuery:userQuery];
        [newsQuery setLimit:50];
        [newsQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
        [newsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            self.followingNews = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];
        [_refreshControl endRefreshing];
    } else {
        PFQuery *inviteQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClubInvites"];
        [inviteQuery whereKey:@"Invited" equalTo:_loggedInUser];
        [inviteQuery whereKey:@"Accepted" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        [inviteQuery countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
            _rowOneCount = number;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];

        PFQuery *requestsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClubRequests"];
        [requestsQuery whereKey:@"Owner" equalTo:_loggedInUser];
        [requestsQuery whereKey:@"Accepted" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        [requestsQuery countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
            _rowTwoCount = number;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];

        PFQuery *myNewsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"News"];
        [myNewsQuery setLimit:50];
        [myNewsQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
        [myNewsQuery whereKey:@"Notified" equalTo:_loggedInUser];
        [myNewsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            self.myNews = objects;
            [_refreshControl endRefreshing];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];

    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        return self.followingNews.count;
    } else {
        if (section == 2) {
            return self.myNews.count;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

//Long tableview configuration method for segumented controller
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSString *cellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;


    if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];

        self.cellImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
        self.cellImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
        self.cellImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        //Create the cell label going into the cell
        self.cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];


        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.cellLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.cellImageView];

        PFObject *eachNews = [self.followingNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        PFUser *notifier = [eachNews objectForKey:@"Notifier"];
        PFUser *notified = [eachNews objectForKey:@"Notified"];
        [notifier fetchIfNeeded];
        [notified fetchIfNeeded];

        NSString *notifierString = [[NSString alloc] init];
        NSString *notifiedString = [[NSString alloc] init];
        NSString *grammer = [[NSString alloc] init];

        NSDate *timeStamp = eachNews.createdAt;
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy h:mm a"];

        NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timeStamp];


        if ([notifier.username isEqualToString:_loggedInUser.username]) {
            notifierString = @"You";
            grammer = @"are";
        } else {
            notifierString = notifier[@"username"];
            grammer = @"is";
        }

        if ([notified.username isEqualToString: _loggedInUser.username]) {
            notifiedString = @"you";
        } else {
            notifiedString = notified.username;
        }


        if (notifier[@"profileImage"] == nil) {
            UIImage *hermet = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ohyeah.jpg"];
            [self.cellImageView setImage:hermet];
        } else {
            PFFile *imageFile = notifier[@"profileImage"];
            [self.cellImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[imageFile getData]]];
        }


        NSMutableString *newsText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        if ([eachNews[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"Follow"]) {
            [newsText appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@.  ", notifierString, eachNews[@"Messages"], notifiedString]];
        } else if ([eachNews[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"New Founder"]) {
            [newsText appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@.  ", notifierString, grammer, eachNews[@"Messages"]]];
        }

        [newsText appendString:timeString];
        NSArray *appendedString = [newsText componentsSeparatedByString:@"  "];
        NSRange dateRange = [newsText rangeOfString:appendedString[1]];
        NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:newsText];

        [attrString beginEditing];
        [attrString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                           value:[UIColor lightGrayColor]
                           range:dateRange];

        [attrString endEditing];

        self.cellLabel.attributedText = attrString;


        self.cellLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.cellLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

        CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(self.cellLabel.frame.size.width  , CGFLOAT_MAX);
        NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                              nil];

        NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.cellLabel.text attributes:attributesDictionary];

        CGRect requiredHeight = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

        if (requiredHeight.size.height > self.cellLabel.frame.size.height) {
            requiredHeight = CGRectMake(0,0, self.cellLabel.frame.size.width, requiredHeight.size.height);
        }
        CGRect newFrame = self.cellLabel.frame;
        newFrame.size.height = requiredHeight.size.height + 20;
        self.cellLabel.frame = newFrame;
    }

    if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        //Invites section
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            if (_rowOneCount == 0) {
                [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
            } else {
                [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                cell.accessoryView = [MSCellAccessory accessoryWithType:FLAT_DISCLOSURE_INDICATOR color:[UIColor orangeColor]];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Invites (%i)", _rowOneCount];

            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
        //Requested section
        } else if (indexPath.section == 1){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            if (_rowTwoCount == 0) {
                [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
            } else {
                [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                cell.accessoryView = [MSCellAccessory accessoryWithType:FLAT_DISCLOSURE_INDICATOR color:[UIColor orangeColor]];
            }
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Requests (%i)", _rowTwoCount];
            //Requested count is greater than 0
        } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

            //Create the ImageViwew that is going into the cell
            self.cellImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
            self.cellImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
            self.cellImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

            //Create the cell label going into the cell
            self.cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];


            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.cellLabel];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.cellImageView];
            if (self.myNews.count == 0) {
                self.cellLabel.text = @"";
            } else {
                PFObject *myNewsObject = [self.myNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                PFUser *meUser = [myNewsObject objectForKey:@"Notifier"];
                [meUser fetchIfNeeded];

                NSDate *timeStamp = myNewsObject.createdAt;
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy h:mm a"];

                NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timeStamp];

                if (meUser[@"profileImage"] == nil) {
                    UIImage *hermet = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ohyeah.jpg"];
                    [self.cellImageView setImage:hermet];
                } else {
                    PFFile *imageFile = meUser[@"profileImage"];
                    [self.cellImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[imageFile getData]]];
                }
                self.cellImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

                NSMutableString *newsText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

                if ([myNewsObject[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"Follow"]) {
                    [newsText appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ you.  ", meUser.username, myNewsObject[@"Messages"]]];
                } else if ([myNewsObject[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"New Founder"]){
                    [newsText appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are %@.  ", myNewsObject[@"Messages"]] ];
                }

                [newsText appendString:timeString];
                NSArray *appendedString = [newsText componentsSeparatedByString:@"  "];
                NSRange dateRange = [newsText rangeOfString:appendedString[1]];
                NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:newsText];

                [attrString beginEditing];
                [attrString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                                   value:[UIColor lightGrayColor]
                                   range:dateRange];

                [attrString endEditing];

                self.cellLabel.attributedText = attrString;


                self.cellLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
                self.cellLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
                CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(self.cellLabel.frame.size.width  , CGFLOAT_MAX);
                NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                      nil];

                NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.cellLabel.text attributes:attributesDictionary];

                CGRect requiredHeight = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

                if (requiredHeight.size.height > self.cellLabel.frame.size.height) {
                    requiredHeight = CGRectMake(0,0, self.cellLabel.frame.size.width, requiredHeight.size.height);
                }
                CGRect newFrame = self.cellLabel.frame;
                newFrame.size.height = requiredHeight.size.height + 20;
                self.cellLabel.frame = newFrame;
            }
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryView = nil;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Some Events";
    }

    return cell;
}

- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        NSArray *headerTitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Invites", @"Requests", @"Notifications", nil];
        NSString *title = [headerTitles objectAtIndex:section];
        return title;
    } else  if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        return @"Following News";
    } else {
        return @"Events";
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            if (_rowOneCount == 0) {
                return;
            } else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showInvites" sender:self.tableView];
            }
        } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            if (_rowTwoCount == 0) {
                return;
            } else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showRequests" sender:self.tableView];
            }
        } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
            return;
        }
    }

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 40;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
            if (self.followingNews.count == 0) {
                return 50;
            } else {
                PFObject *eachNews = [self.myNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                PFUser *notifier = [eachNews objectForKey:@"Notifier"];
                PFUser *notified = [eachNews objectForKey:@"Notified"];
                [notifier fetchIfNeeded];
                [notified fetchIfNeeded];

                NSString *notifierString = [[NSString alloc] init];
                NSString *notifiedString = [[NSString alloc] init];

                if ([notifier.username isEqualToString:_loggedInUser.username]) {
                    notifierString = @"You";
                } else {
                    notifierString = notifier.username;
                }

                if ([notified.username isEqualToString: _loggedInUser.username]) {
                    notifiedString = @"you";
                } else {
                    notifiedString = notified.username;
                }


                NSString *fullString = [[NSString alloc] init];

                if ([eachNews[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"Follow"]) {
                    fullString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@.", notifierString, eachNews[@"Messages"], notifiedString];
                } else if ([eachNews[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"New Founder"]) {
                    fullString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@.", notifierString, eachNews[@"Messages"]];
                }


                CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(200, CGFLOAT_MAX);

                NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                      nil];

                NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:fullString attributes:attributesDictionary];

                CGRect requiredHeight = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

                if (requiredHeight.size.height > 45) {
                    requiredHeight = CGRectMake(0,0, 200, requiredHeight.size.height);
                }
                return requiredHeight.size.height + 50;
            }

    } else {
        if (indexPath.section == 2) {
            if (self.myNews.count == 0) {
                return 50;
            } else {
                PFObject *myNewsObject = [self.myNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                PFUser *meUser = [myNewsObject objectForKey:@"Notifier"];
                [meUser fetchIfNeeded];

                NSString *fullString = [[NSString alloc] init];
                if ([myNewsObject[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"Follow"]) {
                    fullString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ you.", meUser.username, myNewsObject[@"Messages"]];
                } else if ([myNewsObject[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"New Founder"]) {
                    fullString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are %@.", myNewsObject[@"Messages"]];
                }


                CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(200, CGFLOAT_MAX);

                NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                      nil];

                NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:fullString attributes:attributesDictionary];

                CGRect requiredHeight = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

                if (requiredHeight.size.height > 45) {
                    requiredHeight = CGRectMake(0,0, 200, requiredHeight.size.height);
                }
                return requiredHeight.size.height + 50;
            }
        } else {
            return 50;
        }
    }

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    OtherNewsViewController *otherVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showInvites"]) {
        otherVC.segueIdentifier = @"Invites";
        otherVC.navigationItem.title = @"Invites";
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRequests"]) {
        otherVC.segueIdentifier = @"Requests";
        otherVC.navigationItem.title = @"Requests";
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: consider attaching the project here.

Comment: @carlodurso regardless of the length of the class?? It is pretty long

Comment: I mean attaching the project as a file.

Comment: @carlodurso it has been attatched

Comment: I don't have the actual answer for you as I can't run the project. But I see a potential culprit on line 203 and 215: `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {`. There's too much nesting going on. Try to simplify and troubleshoot from here.

Comment: i simplified that....still nothing @carlodurso

Comment: like, I said if both of those array in the two asynchronous blocks aren't zero it works perfectly @carlodurso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found the answer/where the problem was! in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, I was passing in the wrong array when grabbing the objects

```
if (self.followingNews.count == 0) {
                return 50;
            } else {
                PFObject *eachNews = [self.myNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This the array in the first part of the IF statement was not used in the initialization of PFObject. I was using self.myNews instead. I guess figuring out problems really just takes time!